# Python request module - results differ from chrome

Tags: python, web-scraping

I try to scrap this url: http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/2013#!hol=25

Specifically i want all special dates from the US - Year 2013 with the filter "Holidays and some observances". When i go to http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/2013 i can see a lot of holidays, after i applied the "Holidays and some observances" filter i see a table with all holidays i want to scrap. With the "inspect element" function of chrome i figured out that the holiday table contains still all holidays but the one hidden have the class "dn". So i used BeautifulSoap to filter out all the holidays with the class 'dn' and expected to get only those which i can see when i click on http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/2013#!hol=25

Unfortunately that didn't work out so far.

```
r =  requests.get("http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/2013#!hol=25")
print(r.url)
> http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/2013#!hol=25   #URL seems to be right

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

n = 0
for link in soup.find_all('tr'):
   if link.get('class')[0] != 'head':  #removes the 2 head rows of the table
       if link.get('class')[0] != 'dn':
          n += 1
print(n)
> 197  # instead of 17 as in Chrome
```

Since request seems to handle the url in the right way i have no clue why i don't get the same result as in Chrome?

Is it possible that request() doesn't take care of the "#!hol=25" part of the URL?

Comment: `#!hol=25` is a fragment identifier, something a server will ignore. Only client code can interpret that, by which I mean the *javascript embedded with the page*. `requests` won't run Javascript code, it makes a straight-up HTTP request.

Comment: That said, without inspecting the actual results here, note that HTTP servers are also black boxes whose behaviour may be entirely non-deterministic. Many will vary what they return based on various aspects of the request, including the path and the headers of the request. Cookies are part of the headers, the User Agent identifier is, etc, and these can all differ from what Chrome sent.

Comment: You'll have to experiment with looking at the source of what was returned to Chrome (do not use *inspect element*, that's the rendered DOM and may have been altered by code already, use *View Source* from the *View* -> *Developer Tools* menu) and compare that to what was returned to `requests`. If they are the same, only JavaScript remains to explain the difference you see.

Comment: Hm i checked "View Source" and it is as you described. I guess that means i can't scrap the exact table with request() then? any alternatives?

Comment: It depends on what the JS code *does*. Perhaps the information you want is still there in the data, perhaps they used AJAX requests to load additional information. Check the network tab on the page and perhaps try and decipher their JS code.

Comment: I am not sure if i did the right thing but when i check the network tab and refreshing the filter "chromecastcheck.js" pops up.  Is that what you are talking about? *sry i am not really familiar with the whole topic...

Comment: Then perhaps you need to find yourself something to read on the subject of AJAX. This is way too broad to continue to discuss in comments here.

Comment: I was just looking at some page source from that site & I saw this comment: "scripts and programs that download content transparent to the user are not allowed without permission". So they really don't want you to do what you're trying to do. They _do_ provide an [API](http://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/) to make it easy for programs to access their data. The API is not free for normal use, but they offer free test accounts.

Comment: PM2 Ring: i didn't know this! Thx for the info, i guess i will use the API then.

Comment: Martijn Pieters: Thx a lot for your input, i learned quite a bit